# word-wrap inside flexbox not working

Tags: html, css, flexbox, word-wrap

I'm using flexbox, each item consists of picture and text under it. I need to make all pictures same height (width may vary) and text to wrap so it doesn't extend items.

But I managed to enable word-wrap only with justified width, not height.

Note: I need to justify images, not items.

```css
.wrapper1,
.wrapper2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-item {
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.wrapper1 .flex-item {
  width: 150px;
}

.flex-item p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.card-image {
  width: 100%;
}

.card-body {
  padding: 7px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.wrapper2 .flex-item {
  width: auto;
}

.wrapper2 .card-image {
  height: 231px;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper1">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <a href="/comics/novathekeep" title="Нова: Цитадель"><img src="http://warcry.ru/comics/pages/thumb/51.jpg" class="card-image" /></a>
    <div class="card-body">
      <p><a href="/comics/novathekeep">Нова: Цитадель</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <a href="/comics/artanissacrifice" title="Артанис: Великая жертва"><img src="http://warcry.ru/comics/pages/thumb/303.jpg" class="card-image" /></a>
    <div class="card-body">
      <p><a href="/comics/artanissacrifice">Артанис: Великая жертва</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <a href="/comics/kerriganhopeandvengeance" title="Керриган: Надежда и мщение"><img src="http://warcry.ru/comics/pages/thumb/41.jpg" class="card-image" /></a>
    <div class="card-body">
      <p><a href="/comics/kerriganhopeandvengeance">Керриган: Надежда и мщение</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper2">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <a href="/comics/novathekeep" title="Нова: Цитадель"><img src="http://warcry.ru/comics/pages/thumb/51.jpg" class="card-image" /></a>
    <div class="card-body">
      <p><a href="/comics/novathekeep">Нова: Цитадель</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <a href="/comics/artanissacrifice" title="Артанис: Великая жертва"><img src="http://warcry.ru/comics/pages/thumb/303.jpg" class="card-image" /></a>
    <div class="card-body">
      <p><a href="/comics/artanissacrifice">Артанис: Великая жертва</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <a href="/comics/kerriganhopeandvengeance" title="Керриган: Надежда и мщение"><img src="http://warcry.ru/comics/pages/thumb/41.jpg" class="card-image" /></a>
    <div class="card-body">
      <p><a href="/comics/kerriganhopeandvengeance">Керриган: Надежда и мщение</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arrzrsyu/1/)**

First flexbox has items with same width (word-wrap works), second flexbox has items with same height (word-wrap doesn't work).

Comment: is it browser specific issue??

Comment: At least I need it to work in Chrome.

Comment: ok you always have 3 rows in a column or it will differ?

Comment: This flexbox is supposed to wrap its items automatically (that's why I use flexbox). It contains 2-5 items in a row depending on resolution.

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign max-width or flex-basis property

```
.wrapper2 .flex-item {
    flex: 0 1 150px;
}
```

or

```
.wrapper2 .flex-item {
    max-width: 150px;
}
```

Comment: Word-wrap works, but items become messy. So it is not an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you I think, give a try and let me know.

```
.wrapper2 .card-image {
    height: 231px;
}
```

check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bhavikbamania/z97r0Ldz/)

Comment: As in previous answer it makes word-wrap work but breaks the layout of cards.

Comment: sorry I forgot to update it now I have updated my fiddle you can check it I guess thats what you want.

Comment: Thanks, Mr. Pyramid, but with fixed width and fixed height some images get distorted (like that in the center), I want to preserve proportions.

Ideal result will be images with fixed height and preserved proportions (so they can become wider than usual) and word-wrapped text.

Comment: Here is an example of what I want to achieve + word-wrapped text (text doesn't wrap on this page): http://warcry.ru/comics/series/curseoftheworgen/4

Comment: ok I got this check the inspect of your reference you can see they have a fix height of (231px) with width set to  auto similarly you want to preserve the proportion then either set your height to auto or set your width to auto then it will always preserve the proportion currently you are messing with height and width thats why you have proportion issue

Comment: check the updated fiddle and updated answer and yeah here for resize you need to do few media queries in order to fix the last div of  `.wrapper2`

Comment: Hello Mr. Pyramid. I think we spent too much time on this. :) The central image is still distorted. You propose to use JS to fix it? What should this script do exactly?

Comment: media queries will take care of responsiveness of site in different resolutions I recommend you to use bootstrap framework as in your reference link they have used bootstrap for that purpose and if you found my solution somewhat near about the proper solution please upvote it and accepted so that this question can be closed :)

Comment: IF you use bootstrap you will get what you want.

Comment: Hello Mr. Pyramid. I upvoted your answer, but it didn't help me yet. The link I posted is my site, I need this functionality for this page: http://warcry.ru/comics/ I use Bootstrap 3. How it can help me? I use flexbox, Bootstrap uses flexbox starting from version 4. Can you show an example in Bootstrap 3?

Comment: if you use bootstrap you wont't need to worry about media queries anymore

Comment: Ok but how do I do this kind of layout in BS3/BS4?

Comment: you can learn from its official website getbootstrap.com and w3schools.com there learn about the basic concept of grids and responsiveness and then try this you are absoultely good to go coz I have made edits after looking at your reference